# Kotlin, unresolved reference on everything in VSCode

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code

I installed Kotlin plugins for VSCode and created Hello World file `test.kt` but VSCode shows errors (it could be compiled via command line)

[image]

Answer (score 41):

I had this issue when I had both the Kotlin Language by mathiasfrohlich and Kotlin by fwcd extensions installed.

Uninstalling Kotlin by fwcd resolved the problem in my case.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin Not in VS Code. I use mostly IntelliJ now.

Comment: perfect fix for my problem!

Comment: well it's simple, the extension by mathiasfrohlich has just syntax highlight, you won't get any intellisense and auto-completion features.

Comment: That does not fixed the problem if you need the feature like code completion. https://github.com/fwcd/vscode-kotlin/issues/85#issuecomment-1082196395

Comment: Uninstalling fwcd disables compilation, so it's not much of a fix.

Answer (score 12):

if you have the first extension (**kotlin by fwcd**), **Uninstall** it and install the second I mean **by mathiasfrohlich**.

[image]

Comment: That does not fixed the problem if you need the feature like code completion. https://github.com/fwcd/vscode-kotlin/issues/85#issuecomment-1082196395

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by updating the Kotlin version that my build.gradle file referenced.

Bump the version number, then run build and the errors may magically disappear.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that I was using outdated...well, everything. I was relying on Ubuntu's package manager to pull me through.

My project is a flutter Android library.

If you have the same issue, then I'd check the following:

1. Ensure you download the [latest kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/getting-started.html#install-kotlin)
2. Download and install the [latest gradle](https://gradle.org/install/)
3. (Of course, make sure the `PATH` environment variable has the `bin` directory)
4. Restart VSCode/Codium if needed.
5. Since I'm building a **library**, I couldn't do flutter build. Instead I had to build with gradle (basically `gradle sync`)
6. I also had to update my `settings.gradle` file similar to [this post](https://sebhastian.com/plugin-with-id-com-android-application-not-found/)
7. There's more that I had to do, but hopefully that's a good start for anyone that needs it. Basically gradle is the secret.